Adding files to an existing zip file - zip filesize increases, but files don't show
I have a method to create or add to an existing zip file, that either calls ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory() when the zip does not yet exist, or opens the zip using the ZipFile class, and adds files to it. (Note: using .NET Framework, 4.7.2).
The zip file structure should look like this:
XYZLogs_2024.zip
 |
 |- 03/
    | - Log_2024-03-01.log
    | - Log_2024-03-02.log
    | - Log_2024-03-03.log
    | - ...
 |- 04/
    | - Log_2024-04-01.log
    | - ...
 |- 05/
    | - Log_2024-05-01.log
    | - ...

This works perfectly as expected when calling ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(). However, the problem occurs when I try to add files to an existing zip file. The zip file's size grows, but new files/folders never show up in the zip file, not even if I try to extract all. No exceptions are thrown.
Here's the part of the method that handles adding files to an existing zip file:
using (var zip = ZipFile.Open(destinationZipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    var sourceDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectoryPath);
    foreach (var file in sourceDirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var pathInZip = file.FullName
            .Replace(sourceDirInfo.FullName, "") // strip off the folder it's contained in
            .Replace("\\", "/");                 // replace backslashes with forward slashes

        // THIS didn't fix it ...
        /*
        var inFolder = (pathInZip.Contains("/"))
            ? pathInZip.Substring(0, pathInZip.IndexOf("/"))
            : null;
        if (inFolder != null)
        {
            var folderExisting = zip.GetEntry(inFolder);
            if (folderExisting != null)
            {
                zip.CreateEntry(inFolder);
            }
        }
        */

        // what if file already exists in zip?
        var existingEntry = zip.GetEntry(pathInZip);
        if (existingEntry != null)
        {
            existingEntry.Delete();
        }

        // add to zip
        zip.CreateEntryFromFile(
            file.FullName,
            pathInZip,
            compressionLevel);
    }
}

Tried:

As you can see from the code above, I tried creating an entry for the month folders, which did not work.
I also tried commenting out the line that replaces backslashes with forward slashes, in case that was the problem, but that also had no impact.

Would prefer:

I'd prefer to keep all file properties, especially date created/date modified, which is why I'm using the CreateEntryFromFile method.
I would prefer a solution that doesn't require extracting everything from the zip file and recreating the whole zip file, if possible.

I really hope this isn't just a case of something small I've missed!

Make sure that your zip archive entry name/path doesn't start with a slash. Leading slashes are violating the ZIP format specification (https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT, section 4.4.17). While some ZIP utilities/libraries are tolerant of leading slashes, many others are not.
The sourceDirInfo.FullName string probably doesn't feature a trailing [back]slash (unless you created the DirectoryInfo instance with a string that already has a trailing [back]slash), so doing file.FullName.Replace(sourceDirInfo.FullName, "") would leave you with a file path having a leading [back]slash, which is the likely cause of your problem.
(Side note: Using forward slashes as directory separators in ZIP entry file paths is correct, by the way.)

That was exactly the problem! I just stuck a .TrimStart('/') in my method, and now everything's working as it should. I don't think the MSDN documentation I was looking at mentioned anything about entry name/path validity. Thanks!
